# Delete an object and Insert another with same key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Please consider this code:

```
var tmpCurrentRecord = ent.Mytbl.Where(o => o.ID == CurrentRecord.ID).First();                        
ent.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(tmpCurrentRecord, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
ent.Mytbl.DeleteObject(tmpCurrentRecord);

ent.Mytbl.AddObject(NewRecord);

ent.SaveChanges();
```

I want to reset columns's value of the specific record.Because the count of this column is about 70 column, I want to delete record and insert it again with the same primary key. But I get this error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you publish your changes to the actual database? I'm not 100% sure but I think you *flagged* it for deletion. As long as you don't save these changes the record technically still exists.

Comment: Have you tried to call SaveChanges() twice? Once after deletion, second time after insertion. This might fix the issue..

Comment: @PetrAdam No I call it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Detach the old one and then Attach the new object. See this [overview on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb896271%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

That eliminates the need to do 2 SaveChanges() and it should be faster all around (less updating of indexes etc)